# Too many arguments in Nested IF statement

Tags: excel-formula

In excel I am  using Nested IF statement and not sure why I am getting "there is too many arguments in this function". Is it because there is an overlap in the statement?

The Nested IF statement is supposed to output one of the following choices:  HazOp, SIL, LOPA, HazOp & SIL, HazOp & LOPA

```
=IF(AND(C42="HazOp"),"HazOp",IF(AND(C43="SIL"),"SIL"),IF(AND(C44="LOPA"),"LOPA",IF(AND(C42="HazOp",C43="SIL"),"HazOp & SIL",IF(AND(C42="HazOp",C44="LOPA"),"HazOp & LOPA",0))))
```

Comment: Why are you using the AND function if you are only passing 1 argument?

Comment: try this `IF(C42="HazOp","HazOp",IF(C43="IFL","IFL",IF(C44="LOPA","LOPA",IF(AND(C42="HazOp",C43="IFL"),"HazOp & IFL",IF(AND(C42="HazOp",C44="LOPA"),"HazOp & LOPA",0)))))`

Comment: What if C42="HazOp" and C43="IFL" and C44="LOPA"?

Comment: And will they be empty if not one of those, or can some other value be in the cells?

Comment: @Scott Craner They can be empty if not one of those cells

Comment: @Damian What is IFL? I want one of these choices to show or have a blank cell (HazOp, SIL, LOPA, HazOp & SIL, HazOp & LOPA)

Comment: Can they be all three?

Comment: @ Scott Craner nope

Comment: so it is either SIL or LOPA, with the possibility of HazOp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Office 365 Excel use this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" & ",TRUE,C42:C44)
```

If not use this:

```
=MID(IF(C42<>""," & " & C42,"") & IF(C43<>""," & " & C43,"") & IF(C44<>""," & " & C44,""),4,99)
```

Comment: Wow Idk you could do that that way thanks so much :)